# Rails Paperclip interpolate query with reference id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to retrieve a field from an other table in Paperclip interpolatation system.
So far, it's working when I'm using an existing reference number like `3`, but it won't work when I'm trying to use the `container_id` reference field, even if it's save in the database.

Rails displays this error :

```
undefined local variable or method `container_id' for Paperclip::Interpolations:Module
```

**the form**

```
<%= form_for @upload, :remote => true, :authenticity_token => true do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :file %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :container_id, value: @page.container.id %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "submit"%></p>
<% end %>
```

**the model**

```
Paperclip.interpolates('container') do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.get_container(container_id).to_s
end

def get_container(container_id)
  return Container.find(container_id).url
end
```

Is there a way to query another table and use a field with Paperclip interpolate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because container_id is not in the scope of the method you are using (interpolates)

what you do have access to is attachment.instance.

If @upload is a model I suggest you add container_id as a column and then you can just do this:

```
Paperclip.interpolates('container') do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.container.url.to_s
end
```

i don't know if it is because you would need to put more information, like the models involved and the associations. like the Container class

Hope it helps

Comment: Oh that's right, I just needed attachment.instance.container.url.to_s, seems like I totally missed it ! Thanks

Comment: happy to help. Id ask you to up vote the answer for other to find more easily.